# How to synchronously call multiple functions which contain mongoose queries in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose-schema

I want to execute 4 functions in order. Each functions is of the below format. Like create update delete and display. I want to call the display function after completing the other 3 functions. I tried promise method but without any db call it is working in order.When a mongoose call is happening, the order is getting changed.

```
function createProjects(req) {
var projects = req.body.created;
projects.forEach(function (project) {
    var newProject = new ProjectSchema(project);
    newProject.save(function (error, object) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        console.log(object)
    });
});
}
```

How this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the code to wait until one promise completes before starting the next one, using something like `bluebird.each`, the `async` library, or a next callback queue. The first part of that sentence may sound like a *duh* sort of thing, but in node.js `.save` will always return immediately, regardless of when the callback is executed (making it less obvious in the code).

Here's an example with `bluebird.each` I tried to stick to the code style you are using in your example code.

```
    var Promise = require('bluebird');

    function createProjects(req) {
        var projects = req.body.created;
        return Promise.each(projects, function (project) {
            return new ProjectSchema(project).save();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Tip: `newProject.save()` already returns a promise, you don't have to wrap it (or pass a callback to it)

Comment: @robertklep thanks for the tip, I will update when I can. Will make it much more brief.

Comment: i have changed the code as per this, calling the promise like below.

        `createProjects(req)
            .then(updateProjects(req))
            .then(displayProjects(req))`

Still the createProjects is executing after calling displayProjects only

Comment: @viz_tm that's because your code is incorrect, it executes both `updateProjects` and `displayProjects` immediately, it doesn't wait for the `then`'s to resolve.

Comment: @robertklep then how we can wait for the createProjects to be completed

Comment: @viz_tm `createProjects(req).then(() => updateProjects(req)).then(() => displayProjects(req))`

Comment: For updating the project, this method is not working. Is this the correct way?

`return Promise.each(projects, function (project) {
        ProjectSchema.findOne({
            _id: project.id
        }, function (error, object) {
            if (error) {
            }
            object.name = project.name;
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                object.save(function (error, object) {
                if (object) {
                                resolve(object);
                            }
                            })`

Comment: it is like whatever project i am updating, it is not getting displayed or same old project is coming in displayprojects

Comment: issue is resolved. it was an issue with syncTime. thanks to all